# Short story about a man who gets trapped inside a woman's breast

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It's a science fiction short story I read in the late 90's, but I don't know when it was published.

A man is making out with a woman when they get hit by a science experiment and the man is trapped inside the woman's breast. At the end of the story, his body with her breast for a head shows up at her house.

Comment: So, his head replaced her breast initially? Or he's trapped inside it? Did it change the shape?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the appropriately titled "Big Bust at Herbert Hoover High" by Jay R. Bonansinga (1996). It appeared in the *It Came From the Drive-in* collection by Partridge and Greenberg.

From this [review](https://marzaat.com/2016/07/11/it-came-from-the-drive-in/):

> “Big Bust at Herbert Hoover High”, Jay R. Bonansinga — Enjoyable and absurd story of an adolescent fixated on female breasts and their lingerie accompaniments. Thanks to one of those convenient nuclear accidents at his father’s work, the lad finds himself fused and joined to his girlfriend’s left breast – a fate he comes to gratefully accept. I liked the image of the girl’s left breast supplanting the boy’s head a lá the movie The Fly. I also liked the voice of actor Russ Tamblyn epitomizing cool.

Comment: @Giacomo1968  Presumably, a character makes reference to the voice of Tamblyn as being the apex of coolness, as far as they are concerned.  Or, perhaps, a paragon of coolness having the voice of Russ Tamblyn?  In either case, the reviewer enjoys the reference.